# javac set default heap size for java permanently

Tags: java, javac

I'm trying to set the `javac` heap size for it's java vm permanently. I have set my `JAVA_OPTS` to `-Xmx64m` which works great when I call `java` but not `javac`. I still get heap size issues. Is there a different variable I can set in my .bashrc to change is permanently?

When I run `javac -J-Xmx64m` it works great. So I just need a way to make that `-J-Xmx64m` option permanent.

FYI - I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 with OpenJDK 1.7

Comment: I believe you can find your solution here...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104115/how-do-you-increase-the-maximum-heap-size-for-the-javac-process-in-borland-jbuil

Comment: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS as mentioned in that link did sort of work. I managed to get it to at least recognize that the option was set. But now all of a sudden I'm still getting the heap issues even though it worked when I set it previously.

Answer (score 5):

Very pragmatic solution (assuming you use bash):

```
# find out where javac lives, and note the path
$ which javac
/path/to/javac
$ vi ~/.bash_aliases
alias javac='/path/to/javac -J-Xmx64m'
```

Comment: how 'bout a little `. ~/.bash_aliases`? :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ubuntu and OpenJDK 7, the default for a 64-bit process should be 1/4 of the main memory.  Unless you have a tiny memory of less than 256 MB, the default would be 64MB of more anyway.

I suggest you

- have the 64-bit JVM which defaults to a larger size.
- have plenty of memory, ideally 16-64 GB for a new machine.

Comment: I can't do that. I'm on a very low end VPS 220mb of RAM. I realize I'm kinda pushing the boundaries. But I'm hoping I can get it to at least run. It won't be doing any heavy work.

Comment: @ChrisKdon You can compile the code anywhere, even on a PC. (This is a key feature of Java)

Comment: That's a good point. I was hoping to be able to do it all on one machine. But I may go with that option. Ultimately it's going to be used with Grails which I thought would need the javac compiler because in development mode it recompiles files on the fly.